# I am unable to read the data from Textfield

Tags: java, textfield, javafx-11

I've been trying to make a simple calculator using JavaFX and I am very new to this. I have two `TextField`s and rest of the buttons are operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. The problem is that whenever I perform a calculation and press the equal, I get zero as a result. The calculator is not performing calculations for any of the operators. Kindly help me with this as I am unable to understand why is this happening. Below is the code of Controller file.

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Label result;

    @FXML 
    private TextField num1, num2 ;

    private String operator = "";
    private int number1, number2;
    //private boolean start = true;
    private Model model = new Model();
    
    @FXML
    public void processNumbers(ActionEvent event) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void processOperators(ActionEvent event) {
        String value = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
        if (!value.equals("?")) {
            if (!operator.isEmpty())
                return;
             
            operator = value;
        } else {
            if (operator.isEmpty())
                return;
            
            int output = model.calculate(number1, number2, operator);
            result.setText(String.valueOf(output));
            operator = "";
            //start = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand well, when you make an operation and press `=`, you enter `processOperators()`, you validate the first condition `!value.equals("?")` and `operator` is not empty, so the only action performed by your calculator will be `return;`. I think that's why it doesn't make `result.setText(...)`

Comment: Thanks. So the problem is with the if else conditions. I'll check and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied and ran your code. It works. The problem is that the flow is not intuitive (in my opinion).

First you need to enter values in both `TextField`s, i.e. `num1` and `num2`. After you have entered the values, and the keyboard focus is on one of those `TextField`s, you need to press <ENTER> because pressing <ENTER> invokes method `processNumbers` because you set the `onAction` property for `num1` and `num2` in file *Main.fxml*

After entering the numbers and pressing <ENTER>, you press one of the operator buttons, i.e. `/` or `*` or `+` or `-`.

After you press one of the operator buttons, you press the `?` button and the correct result is displayed.

By the way, I think that the `Clear` button does not work correctly. You should write a separate method that performs a *clear* operation and change the value of `onAction` for that button in the FXML file to the new method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your instructions and it worked. And Yes, I am going to add the functionality of clear button now.